# Plugin to Remove Double Spaces in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am trying to create a plugin to remove double spaces from a CKEditor document. I came up with a very simple solution but I don't think it is necessarily the best solution and after running it, the cursor moves back to the top of the document.

Here is what I have so far:

```
data = editor.getData();
result = data.replace('&nbsp; ', ' ');
editor.setData(result);
```

Basically it is getting everything in the editor, replacing the double spaces, and putting it back. Is there a better way to do it? Is there a way to have the cursor stay in the same place it started before running the command?

Comment: The first question is: why do put data back into editor once you clean it up? It's enough to filter it out when saving editor's data. Isn't it?

The second question is: when do you do that? On `keyup`? While saving? 

If you **really** want to do this for some reason when editor is still running, get familiar with [CKEDITOR.dom.selection.createBookmarks](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection-method-createBookmarks) and [CKEDITOR.dom.selection.selectBookmarks](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.selection-method-selectBookmarks).

Comment: Also, some browser sometimes do ' &nbsp' for the double space, so it might be in either order. What if there is '&nbsp;&nbsp;'? Multi-pass or regex replacement is the really sure way to get rid of them. I actually do it server side during the saving phase.

Comment: I could do it server side, however, the content creators prefer a button because a lot of time they are pasting in content from a OCR'd PDF which sometimes adds a lot of random spaces. So I want them to click a button and it removes any double spaces, if there are triple or quadruple spaces, they can just keep hitting the button until it gets down to one.